# What is the minimum energy required to dessicate an ethanol+water azeotropic solution

Tags: thermodynamics

I am wondering, how can we compute the minimum theoretical energy required to separate ethanol from a cold azeotropic water-ethanol mixture?

Are there industrial processes that are close to the theoretical performance? how much energy would be required in practice to dessicate azeotropic ethanol? Would this be just work or heat?

Comment: No energy is required to do this task. You just have to add enough desiccant agent like calcium chloride to eliminate the water.

Comment: @Maurice CaCl2 forms CaCl2 . 3 EtOH, so not really a good choice.

Comment: Industrial process uses water elimination by destillation away the ternary azeotrop with benzene.

Comment: After an initial distillation for purification and drying up to approx 95% of ethanol, drying with [molecular sieves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_sieve) becomes more and more attractive ([example](https://www.interraglobal.com/applications/dehydrating-ethanol/)).  You pass the solvent, remove the dry solvent from the granules by filtration, dry the molar sieves by heat and vacuum, and recycle the (re)activated cold molar sieves in the next batch.  So you may skip use of benzene and an additional distillation setup.

Comment: @Buttonwood Yes, that is true, I have forgotten to mention it.

Comment: Energy *is* required, but it is the very least of our concerns.

Comment: @Buttonwood thanks for your answer! This process of molecular sieves filtration, how much energy does it require when taking into account the recycling of the sieves? Is there some kind of figure/table of how many MJ/kg of ethanol are required?

Comment: @ChristianClaudel I don't know where to get the data. At lab scale, one evacuates a round bottom flask with an oil pump ($< \pu{0.1 mbar}$) /Schlenk line anyway in use and a heat gun at  $\approx \pu{200 ^\circ{}C}$; once done & cooled to ambient temperature, the content is poured into the liquid (static method). The dynamic method in (alternating) tube reactors with scales better (génie chimique/process chemistry), here regeneration purges the reactor bed with hot dry nitrogen gas over hours (sometimes heating jackets) typically without vacuum (for mechanical reasons of the reactors used).

Comment: The amount of heat needed to regenerate the sieves depends on the capacity of the molar sieves (one can adjust by porosity), and their loading (depends how much they adsorbed/how long they were used). And in a tube reactor, you need pumps to move the liquid across a packed bed (mechanics of fluids), but with flux not too high as you need some residential time to get the adsorption to advance *well enough*.

Comment: Just as an appetizer in addition to Kirk-Othmer (https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/0471238961.1315120511210812.a01.pub2, https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/0471238961.0418250913030315.a01.pub3) there is an open access publication in *Industrial & Engineering Chemistry Research* by Jović *et al.* which, though about dichloromethane instead of ethanol, gently taps into the topic «Adsorptive Water Removal from Dichloromethane and Vapor-Phase Regeneration of a Molecular Sieve 3A Packed Bed», Ind. Eng. Chem. Res. 2017, 56, 5042–5054 (https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.iecr.7b00433).

Comment: As the enthalpy change of mixing is negative and the entropy change of mixing is positive, I would expect the negatively taken change of Gibbs energy of mixing would be the minimal theoretical energy needed to separate them.